# Etherscan token tracker inquiry

Tags: etherscan

I have an inquiry about etherscan.

I can check tokens' prices here using Token Tracker.
What I am wondering is how you manage to measure the prices of these tokens.
Where does it get price data and how does it manage to calculate it?

I'm really looking forward to your answers.

Answer (score 0):

> What I am wondering is how you manage to measure the prices of these tokens. Where does it get price data and how does it manage to calculate it?

Tokens trade at different values in [different markets](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/tron/#markets). I suspect that EtherScan shows an average/aggregate value that it calculates by using a weighted average of these markets. They could either do it themselves, by only looking at the markets they care about, or get the data from elsewhere, like [CoinMarketCap](https://coinmarketcap.com/).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/etherscan/comments/8rd0uv/how_do_i_get_the_price_to_show_on_etherscan_for/e110xf3/?context=8&depth=9) Etherscan obtains token prices from [CoinMarketCap](https://coinmarketcap.com).